# How to render multiple documents in single page in browser using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my application `Employee(Entity)` can have many `Document(Entity)`. An employee can upload his documents on my website. I want to give a view option to the employees to see all his documents. I can show only one document in the browser whenever the user clicks on the view button. But I don't know how to show all documents all together in the browser whenever a user clicks on the view button.

## Here is my code for showing only one document.

```
@GetMapping("/showDocument")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> showDocument(
            @RequestParam("employeeId") int employeeId
    ) throws IOException, SQLException {

        Employee employee = employeeService.findById(employeeId);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = null;
        if (employee != null && employee.getDocuments() != null) {
            Document document = employee.getDocuments().get(0);
            InputStream inputStream = document.getContent().getBinaryStream();
            httpHeaders.setCacheControl(CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
            httpHeaders.set(CONTENT_TYPE, document.getContentType());
            byte[] media = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(media, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return responseEntity;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I had to design this solution, I would not fetch all the documents in one call as this would be heavy on network and would be slower as well. Infact I would just fetch the metadata to show documents in form of thumbnails and on demand fetch the specific document when a user click on specific thumbnail.